# How to change base.ir.ir_ui_view field definition

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-view

I want to change definition of field of class View residing in addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py.

Found [solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/998870/Odoo-custom-view-module) for odoo 8, but it no longer works. What the approach to do the same operation in odoo 10 (11).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is quite broad and therefore hard to answer. The indicated solution defines a whole new view type, which is quite rare, but should generally work the same way in newer Odoo versions. Please ask a more specific question what you are trying to do, what you tried, and what does not work as expected/desired.

Comment: Thanks ! Particularly want to change `fields` field.

Comment: Ok... what do you want to change about the `fields` field - from what to what? And what do you want to achieve with this?